# run spark-operator on k8s cluster

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, spark-operator

Hi all i'm trying to run the pi spark exemple on my k8s cluster.
I have installed spark operator, pulling the image and run this command:

```
kubectl apply -f ./spark-pi.yaml
```

Documentation [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator/blob/master/docs/quick-start-guide.md#using-the-mutating-admission-webhook).

When I log the driver pod it gives this:

```
pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.19.6/tools/cache/reflector.go:156: Failed to watch *v1.Pod: failed to list *v1.Pod: pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:namespace:spark-operator-spark" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" at the cluster scope
```

When I run the operator pod, it gives this:

```
pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.19.6/tools/cache/reflector.go:156: Failed to watch *v1.Pod: failed to list *v1.Pod: Unauthorized
```

here my rbac.yaml file for ClusterRole and ClusterRoleBinding ( same file as the origin helm charts file): https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator/blob/master/charts/spark-operator-chart/templates/rbac.yaml
Any solution?

Comment: The documentation you mentioned [states](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator/blob/master/docs/quick-start-guide.md#running-the-examples) you may need to change service account. Have you done it?

Comment: @PawełGrondal: yes i have changed the created serviceaccout named "spark-operator-spark" in my spark-pi.yaml file but still KO... may be could be somthing repating to the Rolebinding in order to map sparkoperator.k8s.io et spark-operator-spark ?

Comment: Please add your ClusterRole and ClusterRoleBinding to your original post.

Comment: @PawełGrondal done, please see origin post

Comment: @PawełGrondal any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

Before installing the Operator you need to set:
ServiceAccount
RoleBinding
Namespace for the Spark applications (optional but very recommended )
Namespace for the Spark Operator     (optional but very recommended)

see the example below :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: spark-operator
```

---

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: spark-apps
```

---

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: spark
  namespace: spark-apps
```

---

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: spark-operator-role
  namespace: spark-apps
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
kind: ClusterRole
name: edit
subjects:
 - kind: ServiceAccount
name: spark
namespace: spark-apps
```

taken from https://gist.github.com/dzlab/b546a450a9e8cfa5c8c3ff0a7c9ff091#file-spark-operator-yaml